# How to use a table's content for querying other tables in BIgQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My team and I are using a query on a daily basis to receive specific results from a large dataset. This query is constantly updated with different terms that I would like to receive from the dataset.
To make this job more scaleable, I built a table of arrays, each containing the terms and conditions for the query. That way the query can lean on the table, and changes that I make in the table will affect the query without the need to change it.

The thing is - I can't seem to find a way to reference the table in the actual query without selecting it. I want to use the content of the table as a WHERE condition. for example:

table1:

terms
[term1, term2, term3]

query:

```
select * from dataset
where dataset.collumn like '%term1'
or dataset.collumn like '%term2'
or dataset.collumn like '%term3'
etc.
```

If you have any ideas please let me know (if the solution involves Python or JS this is also great)
thanks!

Comment: please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can better help you

Answer (score 0):

You can "build" the syntax you want using Procedural Language in BigQuery and then execute it. Here is a way of doing it without "leaving" BQ (meaning, without using external code):

```
BEGIN
DECLARE statement STRING DEFAULT 'SELECT col FROM dataset.table WHERE';
FOR record IN (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(['term1','term2','term3']) as term)
DO
SET statement = CONCAT(statement, ' col LIKE "', '%', record.term, '" OR');
END FOR;
SET statement = CONCAT(statement, ' 1=2');
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! while there are easier ways outside of bq, this sure is a great solution for my problem. thanks again:)